# Module and how to use it in the situation below

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
public class AirplaneLab
{
private int [][] first;
private int [][] economy;
private boolean [] seat;
private boolean okay;
private boolean okayokay;
public AirplaneLab()
{
}
public AirplaneLab(int [][] first1, int [][] economy1)
{
}
public boolean viewFirstClass(boolean set[], int [][] first, int [][] economy)
{
    if (okay = true)
    {
        boolean seating1[] = new boolean[20];
        for (int  i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if(seat[((j + 1) + (i * 4)) - 1])
                {
                    System.out.print("x ");
                    seating1[i * j] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("o ");
                    seating1[i * j] = flase;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("The x's are the sets that are taken, o's are not");
        return seating1[];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean viewEconomyClass(boolean set[], int [][] first, int [][] economy)
{
    if (okayokay = true)
    {
        boolean seating2[] = new boolean[30];
        for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if(seat[((j + 1) + (i * 3)) - 1])
                {
                    System.out.print("x ");
                    seating2[i * j] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("o ");
                    seating2[i * j] = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("The x's are the sets that are taken, o's are not");
        return seating2[];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public void decision()
{
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
    System.out.println("1 for “booking in first class”");
    System.out.println("2 for “booing in economy class”");
    System.out.println("3 to view seating chart for first class ");
    System.out.println("4 to view seating chart for economy class");
    System.out.println("0 to exit");
    System.out.print("? ");
    while(true)
    {                                                                                       
        int mOpt = input.nextInt();                         
        if ((mOpt == 1) || (mOpt == 3))
        {
            if (mOpt == 1)
            {
                okay = true;
                System.out.println("Based on the following setting arrangement, please pick a window middle or end seat");
                viewFirstClass(boolean set[], int [][] first, int [][] economy);
                for (int  i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    {
                        if (seating1[i * j] == true)
                        {
                        if ((i * j) ________________)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the code above, where the blank is:
The last if statement before all of the closed brackets:
I was wondering how you would use module there.
Let's say I wanted to do (i * j) module of 4; how would I do that? Can you fill in the blank? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean *modulo*?

Comment: `(i * j) % 4` ... the percent sign is the modulus operator in Java.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, yes, that works thank you

Comment: You can type you answer below, so that I can give you credit for it

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some thing (modulo) like

```
  if ((i * j) mod 4 )
```

in java ,the syntax would be

```
if ((i * j) % 4 )
```